# How to make my 1-year-old really chew food and not just for a second and then swallowing it whole?

Tags: toddler, eating

My 1-year-old eats solid food and has been since about 9 months. However he just makes a chewing motion mainly chewing his tongue and then swallows the food whole. 
I am not eating at the same time as him. I do make the motions and show him with his food though. I do make most food softer than I'd like to. Any suggestions on how to help me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you eat at the same time as him? I've been telling mine to chew and have been doing the motion (with exaggeration) with my own food to show them how, and it helped.

Comment: I am not eating the same as him. I do mKe the motions and show him with his food tho. I do make most food softer than I'd like to. Thank you guys so much for taking time out to make some great suggestions and provide advice.

Comment: What kind of food is he trying? 
We started out with little pieces of everything: boiled carrots, steamed broccoli... to the point where the veggies get mushy and almost melt in the mouth. Then pieces of soft cheese and little bits of chicken. For the fruits, blueberries cut in half are perfect, or ripe banana bite size. 
We cut everything in small pieces that even if they swallow whole, it can't be dangerous, but they still learn how to chew.

Answer (score 5):

Eating is a skill like anything else.  It takes practice.  The vast majority of kids figure it out all on their own, and your son is still too young to be worried about it.  Just give him softer food in small portions until he gets the hang of it.  When you feed him, try to place the food on his teeth instead of on his tongue.  If he's still having trouble in six months or so, consult your pediatrician.